# PHP login security

Tags: php

This is how I'm building a login system:

**Login:**

1. Check username and password supplied by user with the database.
2. If username and password is correct, store ***only user ID*** in session, something like:

   $_SESSION['userid']=$userid;
3. If User has checked the option to stay logged in, then set 2 cookies, 1 with userID and other hashed string.

**To check if user is logged in:**

1. Check if Session exists, the user is logged. **is it ok?**
2. If session does not exist, check if both cookies, userID and hashed string exist.
3. If Both cookies exist, validate them.

As the Session is stored in the server, is it secure to store only userID ? Can a user pretend to be other user and store his userID in the session and log in as him?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this method is very insecure. I can sniff traffic, intercept your cookies, and your system will accept me as an authenticated user. You are making the assumption that if you get a cookie with a userid and the hashed string, then that user is the same person that originally authenticated to create the cookie. That is a poor assumption, because cookies travel in plain text (unless you encrypt them), so as long as I can grab a cookie, I can pretend be whoever sent that cookie, and your system doesn't know any better.

Edit:

If you are going to use unencrypted cookies, why not just store the session_id in a database table? That way, at least someone that gets hold of a cookie won't have a valid username. Create a sessions table, and when someone successfully authenticates add a row with their user_id and the session_id. Each time a page is loaded, check to see if the session_id in the cookie matches a row in the sessions table. If yes, you can assume the associated user_id is the authenticated user. This approach is just as secure as the one you suggested (i.e. not very), but it's less complex and doesn't give away valid usernames.

Comment: That is true in every case where communication is not encoded with SSL.

Comment: yep. that doesn't invalidate the point. He is asking if his approach is secure. The answer is "no", it's not secure.

Comment: How would you recommend implementing a secure 'remember me' feature then?

Comment: Maybe not secure for military purposes but secure for the vast majority of websites out there.

Comment: @vbence - it's that mentality that has resulted in something like 80% of web apps being vulnerable to xss and sql injection. if you encourage people not to understand and care about security, the problems never go away.

Comment: @RDL - just use SSL. cookies would travel back and forth encrypted instead of plain text. Someone could sniff traffic and have no way to see the contents. Then, whatever identifier is in the cookie can be used to "remember me" the same as is being discussed here. It would just be secure.

Comment: @David: I meant, if a user remembers the password, then first cookie is plain username, but the second cookie would be some hashed data of the user, for example userID (not password) etc. Now, if cookie username and password both exist, then i will check validate the hashed string with database. Is it still very insecure? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Unless you are using SSL, the cookie contents are plain text and can be captured / retransmitted by other people on the network. If SSL is not an option for you, I would go with what I suggested, which is to just use one cookie and only include the session_id. That user will be "remembered" as long as your sessions are valid on the server.

Comment: David, it would be interesting to check some statistics how many home pc-s have worms or other spyware and how many passwords get catched by hyjacking internet traffic. Yes it is a possible attack vector in a textbook but there are thousands of things more important then "Just use SSL".

Comment: @vbence: not sure what your point is. He asked if his authentication solution was secure. It's not. Just because there are other attack vectors out there doesn't mean he shouldn't consider encrypting credentials that are traversing the internet in plain text.

Comment: @vbence: The fact that there are *also* other threats doesn't invalidate @David's point; *ad absurdum* your point would be "the biggest vulnerability are users who CLICK HERE FOR DANCING HAMPSTERS; this is unavoidable, therefore no protection is ever useful". Do you leave your car doors unlocked just because there's an electronic lock on the ignition system? Defence in depth and all that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible and very extended, this kind of attacks are called [Session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) and in your system (as David said) anyone who sniff your traffic, or have access to the user's drive and steal his cookies, may supplant a logged user.

The best protection is, of course, SSL, but if you can't use it in your website there are other things that can prevent (but not fully protect against) this attacks:

- Save info about the user **in the server-side** when he login, good candidates for this are the IP and the [user agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), but any other data that don't change in the entire session can be valid.
- You can regenerate the session ID in every request, with this if the session ID is leaked the attacker must use it before the real user do any other request, but beware because every time the session ID is regenerated (in PHP at least) **the user's session data is rewited**, so this can be expensive if you have a lot of users or if you save many data of every user (this means that, if you're saving the session data in a file, the file will be deleted, created, and writed again).

Well, right now I can only think in these two, it's not much but at least you will put an extra complication to the attackers.

One more thing, don't trust the user's cookies, they can be changed by the user (or the attacker) at any time, treat it like any other user input.

PD.: Sorry for my horrible english, I'm truly trying to improve it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

you could add an ip that the user id should belong to (in your database), that adds a little extra security - it might not always be the best solution

Comment: You shouldn't do this. It breaks the Internet for a lot of people who might have a different IP between requests.

Comment: @meagar Lots of peole have dynamic IP addresses which "can change at any time", but how often do they relly change?

Comment: @vbence It has nothing to do with dynamic IPs. Lots of people are behind networks that have multiple public-facing IPs, and for those people it's a serious problem.

Comment: @vbence: Public WiFi and NAT = FireSheep. Welcome to 2010. Oh, btw newsflash: IPv4 address pool is now officially depleted, so NAT (multiple users on the same apparent IP address) will become *more* common in the near future. Also, mobile users can (and do) get re-assigned different IP addresses from the ISP's pool as they move around (and guess what: 2010 was the year of the mobile computing, and that's not going away either).

Comment: Public wifi does not neccesarily mean unencrypted. And yes, you're right, the danges of unencrypted wifi are great. The reality is users don't know about it so site owners should worry instead. Great point. - I just don't get where that amount of arrogance comes from.

Comment: @vbence The arrogance was unwarranted, but his point is valid. Binding a session to one IP address is no longer good advice. The best sites provide an *option* to do this, for savvy users who know their IP is static or nearly static. But it is absolutely not a good idea to enable this by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ok to check if the session exists and also check that the user id is greater than zero.

The 'remember me' function is subject to sniffing as it's not over ssl, however that is how 'remember me' functionality is done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is happening via SSL, my biggest concern is your first step:

> 1. Check username and password supplied by user with the database.

You should be hashing passwords, and comparing the hash of the user-supplied password against the previously hashed password stored in your database.

You also don't have to worry about storing *only* the user ID in the session array; the session is stored server-side and is as secure as the rest of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I forgot to mention the passwords are hashed.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem is that everything is being stored in cookies. If someone somehow manages to get their hands on the Session ID, then they've also got the username and hashed string.

Chris Shiflett suggests [creating some kind of fingerprint](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-hijacking) from the User-Agent string, or some other regular header, and storing it in a GET variable.

One way to bump up security is to have *everything* sent over SSL. Any time any kind of potential information is sent or received (such as the Session ID in a cookie), make it encrypted - not just the login form.

Answer (score -1):

It is mostly correct but I don't agree with the cookie-option. This way if someone gets the two cookies can move them to a different computer and still use them.

The "remain logged in" function should be restricted to that computer. A possible solution is that if the user wishes to remain logged in you set the lifetime of the session to 1 week or so. Also you have to store the user's IP address, User-Agent and possibly X-FORWARDED-FOR header, and check them on every pageload against the stored values.

Comment: IP Addresses change for most people. User-Agent and headers are easily spoofed.

Comment: I never said to use these instead of the password. These are boundaries which can limit attack vectors. If you utilize this, then a stolen session ID will not be usable from a third site.

Comment: Hmm, the IP check is simple (eliminates the lowest-hanging fruit, yes), but most of the session hijacks won't come from East Elbonia: they will be from your network segment; worse if you're NATed (you most likely are) - then an IP check adds no security, while adding illusion of more security. See also: http://codebutler.com/firesheep-three-weeks-later-fallout